# Visualizing a Decision Tree in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Is there a way to 'declump' the following tree on Jupyter Notebook? Its a simple decision tree but I do not know what is making it look collapsed. Here are the relevant code snippets and the tree itself.

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 8)

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import collections
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


#some more code


# Some feature values are present in train and absent in test and vice-versa.
y = df_train['Should_Vacation_there']
df_train, df_test = intersect_features(train=df_train, test=df_test)
df_train

#training a decision tree
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=17)
dt.fit(df_train, y);

#displaying the tree
plot_tree(dt, feature_names=df_train.columns, filled=True,
         class_names=["Should go there", "Shouldn't go there"]);
```

[image]

Comment: Check the size of the axes you are plotting the figure on. You can increase the `figsize` parameter in `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` to increase the size of the axes. Something like `plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))`.

Comment: One way is to use Graphviz. Check out [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-scikit-learn-graphviz-matplotlib-1c50b4aa68dc).

Comment: @NikhilKumar That may not solve the problem fully. Scikit-learn has a terrible visualization for decision trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'` is the culprit here. Commenting it results in a well-formatted tree.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import collections
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

%matplotlib inline
#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

iris = load_iris()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 8)

#some more code
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.2)

# Some feature values are present in train and absent in test and vice-versa.
#y = df_train['Should_Vacation_there']
#df_train, df_test = intersect_features(train=df_train, test=df_test)
#df_train

#training a decision tree
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=17)
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

#displaying the tree
plot_tree(dt, feature_names=iris.feature_names, filled=True,
         class_names=iris.target_names);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'` out. With `'svg'` instead, you will get great resolution.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn import tree

# Prepare the data data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Fit the classifier with default hyper-parameters
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1234)
model = clf.fit(X, y)
```

## 1:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
_ = tree.plot_tree(clf, 
                   feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                   class_names=iris.target_names,
                   filled=True)
```

[image]

#2

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
_ = tree.plot_tree(clf, 
                   feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                   class_names=iris.target_names,
                   filled=True)
```

[image]